# Spring cloud gateway AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I've created global route for all incoming requests and face with AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler.

My application.yml

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: global_route
          uri: http://localhost:8082
          predicates:
            - Path=/**
          filters:
            - RewritePath=/service(?<segment>/?.*), $\{segment}
        - id: authorization_route
          uri: http://localhost:8082
          predicates:
            - Path=/key/login
          filters:
            - JWTFilter=RSA512,HS512
```

Logs when I run the application:

```
2020-10-28 09:31:58.606 ERROR 9184 --- [ctor-http-nio-1] a.w.r.e.AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler : [6d5d3da0]  500 Server Error for HTTP GET "/keyfd"

io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: no further information: localhost/127.0.0.1:8082
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.WeightCalculatorWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ HTTP GET "/keyfd" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
Stack trace:
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:330) ~[netty-transport-4.1.52.Final.jar:4.1.52.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:334) ~[netty-transport-4.1.52.Final.jar:4.1.52.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:702) ~[netty-transport-4.1.52.Final.jar:4.1.52.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650) ~[netty-transport-4.1.52.Final.jar:4.1.52.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576) ~[netty-transport-4.1.52.Final.jar:4.1.52.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493) ~[netty-transport-4.1.52.Final.jar:4.1.52.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) ~[netty-common-4.1.52.Final.jar:4.1.52.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.52.Final.jar:4.1.52.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.52.Final.jar:4.1.52.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
```

Thank you for help.

Comment: Networking issue? Connection refused

Comment: I specified in the answer what was the reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error cause is that I specified uri for spring cloud gateway the same as uri I'm running this application. So application started on localhost:8082 and the uri for route was localhost:8082.

Comment: Hi Artemii I am having the same issue wherein the difference is I'm using uri: lb://USER-SERVICE like this, but when I run the application I having the same issue. Could you help